# Use conditional to change variable based on info.plist environment key

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have different environments in my project (named from 1 to 9) and they are set in info.plist "Environment" key.

How can I access those environments in code to change a variable based on the environment the archive was generated from?

For example, supposing I generated an archive on environment n. 9, I want to use the URL "https://example2.com". The bolded part is the one I can't figure out (supposing the rest is correct too):

```
func webViewURLRequest() -> URLRequest {       
    if **ENVIRONMENT = 1** {
        let url = URL.safe(stringURL: "https://example1.com")
    }
    else {
        let url = URL.safe(stringURL: "https://example2.com")
    }
    return URLRequest(url: url)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second attempt url can't be found in scope because you create it inside of an if statement.  Assuming your environment is properly found, you can rearrange your code to something like this just to test it:

```
func webViewURLRequest() -> URLRequest {
    let environment = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["Environment"] as? String
    if environment == "1" {
        return URLRequest(url: URL.safe(stringURL: "https://example1.com"))       
    } else {
        return URLRequest(url: URL.safe(stringURL: "https://example2.com"))      
    }
}
```